# Why some commands don't take input redirection?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, fedora-20

For example, *echo*:

```
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ cat tmp.txt 
Angel
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ echo < tmp.txt

[aesteban@localhost ~]$
```

As you can see, the output is just a blank line. According to my readings some commands are able to take input redirection, eg *mail*:

```
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ mail barney@example.com < tmp.txt
```

So does input redirection only apply for interactive commands (the ones able to wait for input) ? How do determine if a command is interactive (aside from trying)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why some commands don't take input redirection?

The short answer: because they weren't programmed to.

For a program to read from `stdin` (which is the stream that the shell connects to the file specified after `<`) is not automatic. It needs to be coded by the programmer. For that matter, reading from files given on the command line is also not automatic. That is, the contents of those files, whether given by redirection or specified by name, do not magically appear inside the program's variables without extra coding.

If a program was never coded to read from a stream, it doesn't matter whether you put a redirection - it will simply not read from it. By its POSIX specification (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), `echo` is not required to read from `stdin`, and only examines its command-line arguments (and some environment variables). To find out for other programs, you can read the source code, the documentation, or simply try it out as you said :-)

To answer your last question: you cannot really say a command is interactive. You *can* determine whether the input stream it's reading from is connected to a terminal (as opposed to, for instance, a plain file). There are examples in many languages on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Check_input_device_is_a_terminal. You could conceive a mailing program that uses this feature to determine if it's being used interactively (accepting keyboard commands to read mail), or non-interactively (say, to read a mail message from a file). I am not sure how `mail` does it. (Note that `mail` behaves differently when called with or without command-line arguments!)

Answer (score 2):

Most commands that read the content of a file (or files)
whose name(s) are specified on the command line
will read from standard input if no files are specified on the command line. 
Some will also read from standard input if a filename of `-`
is specified on the command line; e.g.,

```
cat file1 - file2
```

will read from `file1`, then standard input,
and then `file2`. 
But, if a command doesn't normally read the contents of file(s)
whose name(s) are specified on the command line,
then it probably won't do anything with standard input, either. 
`echo` never reads from files.

Of course, there are various exceptions:

- The `tr` command always reads from standard input,
  and does not accept filename(s) on the command line.
- If `bc` is invoked with filename argument(s), it reads them,
  ***and then also*** reads standard input,
  unless one of the file(s) has a `halt` or `quit` command.
- Compilers (e.g., the C compiler, which may be called `cc` or `gcc`)
  tend to require (or at least strongly prefer) filename(s) on the command line. 
  `cc` will fail if invoked with no filenames on the command line. 
  `cc -` will read the standard input only if certain options are specified.
- It doesn't make sense to invoke `cmp` or `diff`
  with fewer than two sources of input.  They will fail if invoked
  with no filenames on the command line.  Both of them honor the convention
  that an argument of `-` designates the standard input. 
  `cmp file1` is equivalent
  to `cmp file1 -`; i.e.,
  it will compare `file1` to the standard input. 
  `diff` fails if invoked with one filename argument;
  you would need to say `diff file1 -`.
- And, while `dd` will accept an **i**nput **f**ile specified
  on the command line if it is presented as `if=filename`, e.g.,

  ```
  dd if=my_iso_file of=/dev/sda1
  ```

  (`of` is **o**utput **f**ile),
  and it will read from standard input if you don't specify any **`if`**; e.g.,

  ```
  dd of=/dev/sda1 < my_iso_file
  ```

  it does not accept *command line arguments that **are** unadorned filenames*
  (so, for example, `dd my_iso_file > /dev/sda1` and `dd my_iso_file of=/dev/sda1`
  do *not* work).  (Also, unlike most commands that read from files,
  `dd` will not process more than one input file from the command line.)

(There are probably others.)

Comment: Technically, you can redirect a file into `dd`: `dd status=none < /proc/uptime`

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation.

The echo command does not read from stdin.  Therefore, input redirection does nothing. Bash manual states:

> echo: Outputs args, separated by spaces, followed by a newline.

Man page for `cat`:

> cat - concatenates files and print on the standard output.